# If statement will not run when comparing two strings Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, string, if-statement

I am using Eclipse to run the following code.

I am trying to compare what I'm entering in the TextView to
what I have in my string array. I even went as far as to set
the TextViews text and the string arrays value that I'm comparing
to the same thing before the if statement runs. I feel as though
I'm missing something simple here so maybe someone could point
me in the right direction. Here is some sample code:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

String[] keyWord = {"cow", "hour", "trial", "active", "purpose", "cat", "route", "laser", "fresh", "success" };

Random randWord = new Random();
int secretWord = randWord.nextInt(10);
```

This is where I am comparing the values

```
public void SubmitClick(View v){
    TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
    keyWord[secretWord] = "the";
    TV.setText("the");
    if(keyWord[secretWord] == TV.getText().toString()){

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct guess!",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

When I select the submit button on my device the code never runs.
I tried adding an else in there which is what I wan't and it always
comes back as not equal so I have no idea what I'm missing here.

Thanks

Comment: Please search SO. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must compare Strings with `equals()` method, not with ==.

Comment: If you provide answer remember to beside solution include explanation of problem. Why using `equals` is correct approach, while `==` is not?

Comment: I suppose user3064123 will understand that on his own by checking the links that were already provided. I was just providing a quick answer.

Comment: Thanks! that was definitely it. I let the c# get the best of me ;)